# Can't rebuild index with django-crontab

Tags: django, cron, django-haystack

Here's what I have in my settings file:

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/5 * * * *', 'django.core.management.call_command', ['rebuild_index'],
        {'interactive': False, 'verbosity': 0}, '> /tmp/rebuild_index.log 2>&1'),
]
```

And here's my HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS file:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.whoosh_backend.WhooshEngine',
        'PATH': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'whoosh_index'),
    },
}
```

For some reason after each time 5 minutes I see only one file in `whoosh_index` folder, it's called _MAIN_0.toc, while when I run the same command in shell, I get plenty of files. Of course I can't use search because index isn't built by cron job.

Here's what logs for CRON look like:

```
Oct 15 21:29:01 dmitry-pc CRON[24988]: (dmitry) CMD (/home/dmitry/.virtualenvs/edcat/bin/python /home/dmitry/Dropbox/coding/python/edcat/manage.py crontab run 97fc023295f0c51d14e582acf71513ba > /tmp/rebuild_index.log 2>&1 # django-cronjobs for edcat)
```

`/tmp/rebuild_index.log` is empty.

Comment: If you call `./manage.py rebuild_index` does it work? If yes, what errors are in crontab? List your generated cron file `crontab -l` and try to run your code in terminal.

Comment: when run the output from `crontab -l` it works fine.

Comment: did you check error log? If it runs ok, then problem might be that user running cron does not have proper permissions?

Comment: I've updated the question to include info about logs. It looks fine. And there's one file written each time cron job runs.

Comment: When I run this `python manage.py rebuild_index --noinput` from project root in my virtual environment it works fine. But it doesn't work if I run it from any other directory although there are no relative paths... Weird.